# How would I match the correct hash pair based on a specific string?

Tags: perl

I have a simple page hit tracking script that allows for the output to display friendly names instead of urls by using a hash.

**UPDATE:** I used php to generate the hash below, but used the wrong dynamic page name of item.html. When changed to the correct name, the script returns the desired results. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.

```
my %LocalAddressTitlePairs = (
'https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html' => 'HOME', 
'https://www.mywebsite.com/art_gallery.html' => 'GALLERY', 
'https://www.mywebsite.com/cart/item.html?itemID=83&cat=26' => 'Island Life',
'https://www.mywebsite.com/cart/item.html?itemID=11&cat=22' => 'Castaways',
'https://www.mywebsite.com/cart/item.html?itemID=13&cat=29' => 'Pelicans',
and so on..
);
```

The code for returning the page hits:

```
sub url_format {
local $_ = $_[0] || '';
if ((m!$PREF{'My_Web_Address'}!i) and  (m!^https://(.*)!i)    ) {
    if ($UseLocalAddressTitlePairs == 1) {
    foreach my $Address (keys %LocalAddressTitlePairs) {
    return "<a title=\"$Address\" href=\"$_\">$LocalAddressTitlePairs{$Address}</A>" if (m!$_$! eq m!$Address$!);
    }
    }
    my $stub =$1;
    return $stub;
    } 
}
```

Displaying the log hits will show
HOME with the correct link, GALLERY with the correct url link, but `https://www.mywebsite.com/cart/item.html?itemID=83&cat=26`
will display a random name instead of what it should be, Island Life for this page.. it has the correct link,-- a different name displays every time the page is loaded. 
And, the output for all pages with query strings will display the exact same name. I know the links are correct by clicking thru site pages and checking the log script for my own page visits. 
I tried -

```
while (my($mykey, $Value) = each %LocalAddressTitlePairs) {
return "<a title=\"$mykey\" href=\"$_\">$Value</a>" if(m!$_$! eq m!$mykey$!);
```

but again, the link is correct but the mykey/Value associated is random too. Way too new to perl to figure this out but I'm doing a lot of online research.

Comment: Please post a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. See [mcve]

Comment: `m!$_$! eq m!$Address$!` makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting this wrong but it seems like you're returning in the loop while you iterate over your mapping between URLs and titles. After you check whatever it is you want to with your, just return the mapped value with `$LocalAddressTitlePairs{$_}`

Comment: I used php to generate the hash, but used the wrong dynamic page name of item.html. When changed to the correct name, the script returns the desired results. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

`m!$Address$!` does not work as expected, because the expression contains special characters such as `?`
You need to add escape sequences `\Q` and `\E`

```
m!\Q$Address\E$!
```

it’s even better to add a check at the beginning of the line, otherwise

```
my $url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/?foo=bar"
my $bad_url = "https://bad.com?u=https://www.mywebsite.com/?foo=bar"
$bad_url =~ m!\Q$url\E$! ? 1 : 0 # 1, pass
$bad_url =~ m!^\Q$url\E$! ? 1 : 0 # 0, fail
```